Springboot endpoint with generic request body
I am trying to create a service providing an endpoint which behaves like a proxy. I may receive any headers, and any type of body. I need to perform some ops and then pass the same headers (of course excluding host) and the same request body as to a destination service.
The most important Content-Type(s) are json, stream, multi-part file, multi-part form, and xml.
Is it good to have overloaded endpoint or a generic endpoint with either accept requestBody as an Object or a String?
Note: this is not an opinion question, I would like to understand the challenges and limitations, and hence which one I should go with.

This looks more like you're looking for a request interceptor. Is there a specific reason it should be an endpoint?

I need to perform some ops and then pass the same headers (of course excluding host) and the same request body as to a destination service. sounds like an API Gateway... why reinvent the wheel and not just use an existing project Spring Cloud Gateway?

Choosing between overloaded endpoints and a generic endpoint depends on your specific use case and priorities:
If type safety, validation, and clear error handling are critical, consider using overloaded endpoints.
If you prioritize simplicity, flexibility, and reduced code duplication, a generic endpoint may be the way to go.
